# Checking Full condition of RBR FIFO of LPC2148 UART

Tags: verilog, uart, lpc

1)How do you check whether the RBR FIFO is full in case of LPC2148 UART? I know that the empty condition can be checked using Receiver Data Ready(RDR) of Line Status Register(LSR). But there is no way to check the full condition. I need the full condition of the RBR FIFO to check the overrun error

Comment: Your second question should be asked here as a second EESE question.  [Multiple questions in the same post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) are discouraged.

Comment: ok.will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

The RDA is activated **when the UART0 Rx FIFO reaches the trigger level defined in U0FCR[7:6]** and is reset when the UART0 Rx FIFO depth falls below the trigger level

So use RDA in your case and define trigger level in U0FCR.

Also from user manual:

OE in Line Status Register (page 156): The overrun error condition is set as soon as it occurs. U0LSR1 is set when UART0 RSR has a new character assembled
and **the UART0 RBR FIFO is full**.

You can find everything you need in user manual, but you need to know what are you looking for and just read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any overrun.

- Are you using the control signals RTS, CTS, DTR?
- Do you have an interrupt routine to handle incomming characters? (Not doing so will make you unhappy)
- Have you played with the "RX Trigger Level"?
- Did you had a look at the "Line Status Register" and the "Overrun Error" bit?

Comment: I am actually writing a test bench for the UART designed by a different person.

1) I haven't encountered the signals RTS, CTS and DTR in UART0 of LPC2148. So I am not sure as to how to use them as they are not present in the User manual

2) Receive Data Available checks if the RXFIFO has fallen below the trigger level,it doesn't check the fullness of the RXFIFO.

3) Same as above

4) As I mentioned earlier,I am writing a test bench for a UART designed by a different person. So I have to check whether the Overrun Error is being updated properly or not

Comment: @daut - Have a look at the block diagram. RTS, CTS, DTR are signals/pins on the hardware side. (e.g. RS-232) To preemt future questions I've listed several points. The real answer to your question should be in the last line ;-)

Comment: @daut - Are we talking about a new or FPGA chip? If yes, why are you talking about LPC2148? Test? Send 16 bytes to the UART and have a look at the Overrun Error bit.

Answer (score 0):

In LPC2148 the FIFO buffer needs to be cleared each time a read/ write data(byte or word or Dword) is preformed to/from the tx/rx buffers. Though this is done automatically. There is a need to set the corresponding bits in the UxFCR register.

For example: if both tx and rx interrupts are enabled and the data size is chosen as 1 byte, setting U0FCR=0x07 will clear the TX and RX FIFOs each time their corresponding buffer handles 1 byte data.

Use U0LSR<1st bit> to check whether overrun error has occurred or not. This indicates that the buffer is written again even though it is full.